# Update every row with an incremental value in Mysql

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Using the following query i tried to populate the empty values of a column, with an incremental number, based on the last row.

```sql
select @i := (
    SELECT code 
    FROM products  
    WHERE code <> '' 
    ORDER BY products.id_product  DESC 
    LIMIT 1
);

UPDATE products SET code = @i + 1 
WHERE code = '' 
ORDER BY id_product;
```

So, if the last code is 41100, the next one row that has an empty CODE column should take the 41101, the next one 41102 etc.
Unfortunately, it populates all the empty records with the next one available code, such as 41101, and doesn't incrementing the number as it should.

Where is my fault?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your update does not increase the value of `@i` for each row. It calculates the constant value `@i+1` on every row, without changing the value of `@i`.

I think what you want is this:

```
update products set code = (@i := @i + 1) 
where code = '' order by id_product;`
```

This means every time the expression is evaluated, `@i` is assigned a new value, which is the previous value of `@i` plus one.

Be warned, however, MySQL officially does not recommend using `:=` in this way. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html

> The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that `SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1` evaluates `@a` first and then performs the assignment.

In the example you have, it should work, but more complex examples may not do what you expect.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, finally i solve it, as editing my own query, as following.
in the update command the set parameter should be like this "set code = (select @i := @i + 1)"

Comment: You don't need the "select" in that expression.

Comment: Whilst the question does ask about updates, beaware that for SELECTs, a group by will throw the numbering out of sync and you'll need to wrap your query in an outer SELECT so it correctly processes the returned values